# How give ampersand '&' as program arguments in eclipse debug configuration settings

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I want to debug c++ application using eclipse CDT by using gdb.
C++ application require ampersand "&" character in argument list.

However whenever I give ampersand "&" in a 'Program arguments' windows of eclipse debug configuration, eclipse does not debug the application and application always terminate on startup of debugging.
without give any ampersand '&'  character as arguments for application, eclipse debug application correctly?

How I can give ampersand '&'  as "Program arguments" of application debug configuration?

Please find attached image for reference[image].